# Rails how to Query on Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three tables `Contact`, `Non Medical Needs` and `Medical Needs`. Contact has_many Non Medical and Medical Needs.

Needs have a `fulfilled` boolean column which marks the need as being completed. I need to query all Contact that has any unfulfilled medical or non medical need.

I have tried querying using the or relation but it only returns the intersection of the needs. Here is the query that I came up with

```
Contact.joins(:non_medical_reqs, :medicaL_reqs)
       .where(non_medical_reqs: {fullfilled: nil})
       .or(Contact.joins(:non_medical_reqs, :medicaL_reqs)
       .where(medical_reqs: {fullfilled: nil}))
```

Edit
I'm using Postgresql with Rails 6

Comment: Protip - don't write your entire program in a single line.

Comment: And it sounds like what you want is to use a subquery or having. Knowing which DB and having a [mce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Answer (score 1):

This might work. I've tried it on a similar relation I have in a project and it seems to work. With `or` I can only get it to work with a slightly different structure for the `where` clause.

```
Contact.left_joins(:non_medical_reqs, :medicaL_reqs).where('non_medical_reqs.fullfilled = ?', nil).or(Contact.left_joins(:non_medical_reqs, :medicaL_reqs).where('medical_reqs.fullfilled = ?', nil}))
```

To sanity check this I would pull the following queries and compare the results:

```
Contact.left_joins(:non_medical_reqs).where('non_medical_reqs.fullfilled = ?', nil)
```

and

```
Contact.left_joins(:medicaL_reqs).where('medical_reqs.fullfilled = ?', nil})
```

And make sure the two sets equal the results from the first query.

Comment: You can write that as  `where(medical_reqs: { fullfilled: nil })`.

Comment: @max in the two single queries I show at the end of my answer yes, but if I use that format in the `or` version in my answer I get `ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:references]`. I'm on Rails 5.1.

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24055. It probably has something to do with my app having default scopes. But there are things other than `:references` that cause this too.

Comment: Actually I don't have any default scopes in this app. So not sure why it doesn't like that form.

Comment: Could it be that you have `medicaL_reqs`?

Comment: No, I've checked the query multiple times. There are no misspellings or incorrect capitalization. Read the github link, it's a known issue.